# how to sum rows with condition? (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, sum

i have this df

```
data={"col1":["n",3,"n",5,"n",2,6],
"col2":[4,"n",4,6,"n","n",5],
"col3":[7,"n",0,"n","n",6,7],
"col4":[14,11,22,8,6,"n",9],
"col5":[0,5,"n",3,8,"n",9],
"type":["B","n","n","n","B","A","B"],
"number":["one","n","n","n","one","two","n"]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

i like to have new column that sum all "n" in evry row/
Something like this maybe:

```
df["sum_n"]=df[["list of all col"]].sum("n",axis=)
```

its need to look like this

```
data={"col1":["n",3,"n",5,"n",2,6],
"col2":[4,"n",4,6,"n","n",5],
"col3":[7,"n",0,"n","n",6,7],
"col4":[14,11,22,8,6,"n",9],
"col5":[0,5,"n",3,8,"n",9],
"type":["B","n","n","n","B","A","B"],
"number":["one","n","n","n","one","two","n"],
"sum_n":[1,4,4,3,3,3,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

Comment: Can you indicate the expected output in your question please.

Comment: do you want to count the number of 'n's in each row?

Comment: i edit the question , and yes i like to count all "n" in each row

Comment: also `df.isin(['n']).sum(1)`, for row wise sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
df['sum_n'] = df.eq('n').sum(1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 type number  sum_n
0    n    4    7   14    0    B    one      1
1    3    n    n   11    5    n      n      4
2    n    4    0   22    n    n      n      4
3    5    6    n    8    3    n      n      3
4    n    n    n    6    8    B    one      3
5    2    n    6    n    n    A    two      3
6    6    5    7    9    9    B      n      1
```